# C# list retrieving tuples from Database returns only first tuple available

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I'm retrieving tuples from a MSSQL Database with this query and List:

```
string query3 = @"select * from HistoryMessageValues where IdMessage in (select id from HistoryMessages where IDDevice in ("+listIDs+")) and (DtRicezione between '" + fromdate.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM") + "' and '" + todate.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM") + "')";
List<HistoryMessageValues> totalm= dbMngr.Set<HistoryMessageValues>().FromSql(query3).ToList();
List<HistoryMessageValues> outdoor = totalm.Where(x => x.IdDataModelField==Guid.Parse("9f5d1fe3-27d7-44ee-bea4-02b36897f9af")).ToList();
```

The query wrote explicitly is this:

```
select * from HistoryMessageValues where IdMessage in (select id from HistoryMessages where IDDevice in ('7b6d6ca2-4d87-4334-9477-d96925d992c4' )) and (DtRicezione between '2010-01-01' and '2019-01-08')
and IdDataModelField='9f5d1fe3-27d7-44ee-bea4-02b36897f9af'
```

If I execute the query itself directly to the DB, I'll obtain these tuples:

[image: Tuples obtained through query execution]

As you can see, attributes "value" and "DtRicezione" are different (at least, most part of them) over tuples.

Meanwhile, I'm obtaining only the first tuple replicated hundreds.

Indeed, executing the following cycle, after that 3 lines of C# in my backend:

```
List<HistoryMessageValues> outdoor = totalm.Where(x => x.IdDataModelField==Guid.Parse("9f5d1fe3-27d7-44ee-bea4-02b36897f9af")).ToList(); 
for (int i=0;  i<outdoor.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(outdoor.ElementAt(i).value + " " + outdoor.ElementAt(i).DtRicezione + " " + outdoor.ElementAt(i).IdDataModelField);
}
```

The result is this:

[image: Result after iteraion]

As you can compare the two images, that will be the first tuple available into the DB's table.

Table's script creation:

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HistoryMessageValues](
    [id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [IdDataModelField] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [value] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IdMessage] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DtRicezione] [datetime] NULL,
    [idKey] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your code.  Can you add the CREATE TABLE and INSERT (or EF equivilents) statements to make this a self-contained repro?

Comment: Please could you explain what do you mean?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Updated. I've also added another attribute to the table that's called "idKey" to ensure a unique identifier per each tuple, but it has changed nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ has a little "I don't care policy".

Before I modified the table "HistoryMessageValues" and its own Context relation, it had no **explicit primary key**: indeed, it had one attribute considered as **uniqueidentifier**: "IdDataModelField".

Due two the nature of Guid (into C# is the data type considered for uniqueidentifier columns), the mentioned attribute was considered as **ghost primary key** while processing any kind of query: as you can see, the reported script was considering only the first tuple replicated several times.

So that, I tried to add "idKey attribute as **uniqueidentifier primary key with NEWID() value as default** and of course modified the related class adding the constraint:

```
   entity.Property(e => e.idKey).HasColumnName("idKey");
   entity.HasKey(e => e.idKey);
```

After this update, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Istorn!

Try to use foreach instead your for...

```
outdoor.ForEach( x => Console.WriteLine(x.value + " " + x.DtRicezione + " " + x.IdDataModelField));
```

Try to check you datareader inside your query executor.
maybe it not going to the next row (so your list will receive every time the same row from database).

Comment: Unfortunately I obtain the same result :(

Comment: The problem wasn't the datareader but a blind working of LINQ: see myself answer...